# Propagate WHERE clause in a View to subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to transform this query in a View:

```
SELECT col1,
       CONVERT(decimal(5, 4), SUM(Volume) / CONVERT(float, (
                                        SELECT SUM(Volume) 
                                        FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [..]
                                        WHERE A.CodA = @param1 AND CodB.[Year] = @param2))
        ) AS [VolPercent]
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [..]
WHERE A.CodA = @param1 AND CodB.[Year] = @param2
```

So, I have to filter subquery with same clausule from external query.
What would be something like this:

```
SELECT col1,
       CONVERT(decimal(5, 4), SUM(Volume) / CONVERT(float, (
                                        SELECT SUM(Volume) 
                                        FROM A as C INNER JOIN B as D ON [..]
                                        WHERE C.CodA = A.CodA AND D.[Year] = B.[Year]))
        ) AS [VolPercent]
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [..]
```

How can I do that? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a view without the WHERE and then querying the View with the WHERE clause should give exactly the same results with exactly the same performance. However you need to add the columns you will use in the where clause. So yes, create your view as

```
create view MyView as
SELECT ACod.A, CodB.[Year],
       col1,
       CONVERT(decimal(5, 4), SUM(Volume) / CONVERT(float, (
                                        SELECT SUM(Volume) 
                                        FROM A as C INNER JOIN B as D ON [..]
                                        WHERE C.CodA = A.CodA AND D.[Year] = B.[Year]))
        ) AS [VolPercent]
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON [..]
```

and then your query is:

```
select * from MyView
where A = whatever
and [Year] = whatever
```

Cheers -

Comment: oh no! I was forgetting the CodA, Year columns in SELECT! sure! :)